# Negating "urls" pattern with onBeforeRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
    if (localStorage.on == '1') {
        return {cancel:true};
    }
}, {urls: ["*://*.domain1.net/*","*://*.domain2.com/*","*://*.domain3.com/*"], types: ["script","xmlhttprequest","other"]}, ["blocking"]);
```

I don't see any way I can negate the URL pattern. Basically I want to match and block everything except those 3 domains. I thought of returning cancel:true for  and the exact content for the 3 domains. First of will that work or will one listener "over-take" the other? How can I return the exact content (So no more cancel:true).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Block all javascript/bloatware that doesn't come from the domain or co-domains of a specific website.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765451/chrome-extension-to-efficiently-block-domains , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158297/blocking-request-in-chrome , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663359/google-chrome-extension-how-to-turn-javascript-on-off

Comment: It's not really related to what I am asking. First link talks about blocking SPECIFIC sites, I want to UNBLOCK, specific sites and block EVERYTHING else.

Comment: @lordanis What do you mean by _"UNBLOCK"_? Only you would be initially blocking content, yes?

Comment: So, I want to block every website in the internet from loading external resources except 3 domains. You can think of it as black listing everything except those 3 domains. So I thought there would be a way to negate the search pattern for the URLs but I realized it there is no support. So now I am just analyzing the details variables and checking each URL with the 3 domains I have.

Comment: Also how can I just return the content for the onBeforeRequest to complete the request normally?

Comment: _"So, I want to block every website in the internet from loading external resources except 3 domains."_ Does "resources" include `.css`? Or only `javascript`? By "loading" do you mean prevent the site from loading `javascript` entirely? Or prevent `javascript` from being run while the extension is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example illustrates how to block all requests, except requests to domain1.net and domain2.net:

```
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
       function(details) {
         return {cancel: details.url.indexOf(".domain2.net/") == -1 && details.url.indexOf(".domain1.net/") == -1};
       },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking"]);
```

I can't see any way to negate the URL pattern in [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)

The answer below, provided by Xan, has a better approach to validate the domain1.net and domain2.net URL's.

Answer (score 3):

While the answer by Paulo Prestes is mostly correct (including the fact that "negative" filters are not possible), the filter suggested is trivially bypassed.

Consider: https://example.com/something?foo=.domain2.net/

This is matched by the rule, but obviously not intentional. Adding an unexpected parameter won't affect most pages, and as such it's quite a trivial bypass.

A collection of regular expressions tuned to extract the domain should be more robust:

```
function validUrl(url) {
  // RegEx, explained:
  // ^              at the beginning of the string
  // http           exactly "http"
  // s?             "s" or nothing
  // :\/\/          exactly "://"
  // ([^\/]+\.)?    (one or more not-"/" followed by ".") or nothing
  // domain\.net\/  exactly "domain1.net/"

  return /^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?domain1\.net\//.test(url) ||
         /^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?domain2\.net\//.test(url) ||
         /^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?domain3\.net\//.test(url) 
}

/* ... */
  return {cancel: !validUrl(details.url)};
/* ... */
```

Comment: This also matches `http://notdomain1.net/` and `http://domain1.net.somethingelse.example.com/`. I suggest `/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?(domain1\.net|domain2\.net|domain3\.net)\//.test(url);`

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to keep those 3 separate. Do you have a link to the question where there's an implementation of Chrome match patterns?

Comment: The edit does still not fix the second issue, `http://domain1.net.somethingelse.example.com` still matches. That's why I put a `/` at the end of the pattern. About the question with the implementation of Chrome's match patterns, I think that you have this in mind: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433271/can-i-allow-the-extension-user-to-choose-matching-domains

Comment: Fixed (sorry, not paying enough attention today) and thanks, that was what I had in mind.

Comment: yeah I think this is a nice approach. I will test it when I get a chance

Comment: I would delete my answer and make this answer the correct, if I could. It is a very nice approach @Xan!